Custom sharing on Facebook - will the targets be able to see each other?
There are many similar questions, such as this "recent" one: People can see with whom I shared a post, when I post it with custom sharing
I'd just like a straight answer. "Suppose" I'm sending someone "a message" via a share, while I'd also want others to see that "message". I also don't want them to know who the "message" (it could be a YouTube video, a status, or anything) has been shared with.
So, how does it work today? I barely have a "primary" FaceBook account, let alone secondary to check.
